# Am I allowed to resell Wordpress Premium Plugins under GPL?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, premium

I have seen a few websites around that resell premium plugins and extensions such as the Woocommerce Extensions, is this allowed? Not too sure where to ask this question either.

Comment: Well, what does the license say?

Comment: There is generally no license information provided by these sites. It looks a bit dodgy and have also asked around. Some say it is copyright and some says it is fine. Still not too sure.

Comment: Just because you *can* does not mean that you *should*.

Comment: Yes. You can surely do that because of the GPL license.

Comment: Why the hell was this question closed as off topic. This is very on topic and VALID!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html and http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html

> Except for one special situation, the GNU General Public License (GNU
>   GPL) has no requirements about how much you can charge for
>   distributing a copy of free software. You can charge nothing, a penny,
>   a dollar, or a billion dollars....
>
> The one exception is in the case where binaries are distributed
>   without the corresponding complete source code. Those who do this are
>   required by the GNU GPL to provide source code on subsequent request.

Comment: maybe if you google "gpl liCense" instead..

Comment: So, the short answer is that as long as you get your hands on the plugin code, you can resell it or give it for free.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no license on the plugin that explicitly allows for re-distribution rights, then the answer is no.

If the plugin is licensed under the GPL, then yes.